# Nesting 6 IF statements in excel 2017 and get the #NAME? error

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, syntax-error

Im trying to nest 6 IF statements in my excel spread sheet but I get the error #NAME? which I know is most likely a syntax error. 
However I cant find the syntax error. I read online that you can nest up to 7 IF statements, does this not apply to Excel 2017?

Heres my function:

```
=IF(AND(F2=KWILA, B14=0.14), B38, IF(AND(F2=KWILA, B14=0.9), C38, IF(AND(F2=VITEX, B14=0.9), C39, IF(AND(F2=PINE, B14=0.14), B40, IF(AND(F2=PINE, B14=0.9), C40, IF(AND(F2=MACRO, B14=0.14), B41, H2))))))
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: An easy way to find out the issue (without the help of others of course) is to un-nest these one by one and see which one individually gives you an error.

Comment: @urdearboy - good advice.  DashCode - See "[mcve]" for further explanation of the "how and why".

Comment: `KWILA` should be `"KWILA"` unless you have created a Defined Name. No defined name throws #NAME? error. Same or VITEX, PINE, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining functions in a formula, start simple, with a single function.  Get it working and producing the result you want before making it more complex by adding a second function (or five more).

---

Since your question doesn't include an example of the data you're working with, I can't be sure of the issue, but I suspect you're trying to compare the text (strings) like `KWILA` to the cells (like `A2`).

If so, the problem is that text (strings) needs to be enclosed in `"`***Quotation Marks***`"`.

---

Almost every time I more than 2 nested `IF`'s, there's usually a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing.

In this cas, I split up the formula in Notepad to see what the goal is:

```
=IF(
    AND(F2=KWILA, B14=0.14), B38
    AND(F2=KWILA, B14=0.9),  C38, 
    AND(F2=VITEX, B14=0.9),  C39, 
    AND(F2=PINE, B14=0.14),  B40, 
    AND(F2=PINE, B14=0.9),   C40, 
    AND(F2=MACRO, B14=0.14), B41, 
 ...if none of the above:     H2
```

I encourage you to double check your criteria above - since, at first glance, it looks like a "broken pattern". For example there are two 38's, one 39, two 40's and one 41.

Assuming it's correct, I look for anything I can **group**, and I see that there are only 2 options for `B14`.  So I regroup:

```
=IF(B14=0.14,
   IF( F2=KWILA,     B38
       F2=PINE,      B40, 
       F2=MACRO,     B41,

 IF(B14=0.9,
   IF( F2=KWILA,     C38, 
       F2=VITEX,     C39, 
       F2=PINE,      C40, 

...if none of the above: H2
```

I also noticed that there are only 4 options for F2, so I considered using CHOOSE instead of IF but I'm not sure how B14 relates the the rest of the data (since it wasn't posted) so we'll stick with this simplification for now.

Midway through putting it "back together" I have:

```
=IF(B14=0.14,
   IF( F2=KWILA,  B38, if( F2=PINE,   B40, if( F2=MACRO,  B41, h2 ))),

 IF(B14=0.9,
   IF( F2=KWILA,  C38, if( F2=VITEX,  C39, if( F2=PINE,  C40, h2 ))) 

 h2 )
```

basically 2 set of IF statements.  Note that I used `H2` three times for "**else** confitions" -I'm not happy with this and I can almost guarantee there's a better way, but again, without seeing your data.....

Put back into a formula, we get a slightly more manageable:

```
=IF(B14=0.14,IF(F2="KWILA",B38,IF(F2="PINE",B40,IF(F2="MACRO",B41,H2))),
      IF(B14=0.9,IF(F2="KWILA",C38,IF(F2="VITEX",C39,IF(F2="PINE",C40,H2))),H2))
```

I can't guarantee this will work since I wasn't able to test it, since...  no data included in the question.  You don't need to switch to this if your method works after adding the quotes.

There are still other alternate way this could have been simplified (and easier to understand or change later) which I won't get into now.  Personally, I would have put the values in a table on another worksheet, and used `INXDEX`/`MATCH` to get the values I needed.

  -

Comment: hey don't worry, I got further into that I care to admit.